# Likebox shows differently for different users

Tags: iframe, facebook-likebox

When I use a standard iFrame like box on my site, it shows up fine for most users. Except for myself. In my view, the names under the faces don't show up, and the border is always #ccc, I can't change it. I attached a screenshot to clarify.

[image: Firefox (not logged in) on the left, Chrome (logged into FB) on the right. Settings are the same in both windows.]

This only happens when I am logged in. Thus I thought it was because of my own privacy settings, but that doesn't explain why the border is behaving unexpectedly. I can't find a proper explanation, any thoughts?